# How prevent CefSharp crash from killing my main Application on Winforms

Tags: cefsharp

I have a simple Winforms application.
I've added a ChromiumWebBrowser control on my Form and I'm navigating on various pages.

For unknown reasons, an exception is thrown from Chromium which causes my app to crash

> CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe Description: The process was terminated
>   due to an unhandled exception.)

Is there a way for me to somehow handle that error so my app doesn't crash?
(and maybe reload the current page)

Comment: What version are you using?  Do you have a stack trace? What is the full exception?

Comment: @amaitland I've used 65 and 71.

Comment: @amaitland CefSharp is not the problem.We can reproduce the issue on Chromium itself(latest version). It usually throws AccessViolationExceptions when playing mp4 videos. Actually,the root of the issue seems to be our infrastructure, we use VMs that use Citrix Receiver and apparently they are not very happy with videos on Chromium. I do have stacktraces from dump files.Do know if you need them.

Comment: How does Chrome behave?  Does the tab die semi gracefully or does the browser itself crash? Have you tried disabling gpu acceleration?

Comment: @amaitland Chrome throws the "aw snap" message, I have   crash dumps but I'll check them tomorrow. Yes,we've tried disabling gpu acceleration but the problem persists. It seems to be gpu related because all the crashes we've seen so far were in rendering/UI code. It looks like outside the VMs,everything works fine. We'll run more tests tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Have you opened a bug with Chromium?  What version of chrome are you testing with?  It's possible they've improved the exception handling even if they didn't fix the bug in newer versions,  you are using an outdated version of CefSharp.  You can try opening chrome://crash and chrome://gpucrash in CefSharp,  both should trigger http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestHandler_OnRenderProcessTerminated.htm

Comment: @amaitland I’ll create a bug if I can provide reproduction steps.I’ll try to update to the latest version too.I’ve implemented the onRenderTerminated but it doesn’t seem to be called but I’ll double check.thanks